# implementing operator * in C++

Tags: c++

```
class Rational {

 const Rational operator*(const Rational& rhs) const

  ...
};

 Rational oneHalf(1,2);

 Rational result = oneHalf * 2;   // fine (with non-explicit ctor)
 result          = 2 * oneHalf;  // error! (even with non-explicit ctor)
```

It was mentioned by scott meyers in Effective C++ book as below

Even when Rationl's constructor is not explicit, one compiles and one doesnot. Reason is given as below:

It turns out that parameters are eligible for implicit conversion "only if they are listed in the parameter list".

The implicit parameter corresponding to object on which member function is invoked -- the one  "this" points to -- is
 never eligible  for implicit conversions.  That's way first call compiles and the second one doesnot.

My question is what does author mean in above statment "only if they are listed in the parameter list" ? What is parameter list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write an operator, try to think of it in terms of an explicit function call.

```
Rational oneHalf(1, 2);
Rational result = oneHalf.multiply(2); // Ok, can convert
Rational result = 2.multiply(oneHalf); // OWAIT, no such function on int.
```

Since there is no such operator on an int, the compiler doesn't know how to handle oneHalf to make the call work, and throws an error. The "Parameter list" in this case is the argument to the operator. You need to make a free function.

Comment: his question is diffferent than what you're trying to answer :|

Comment: I edited it slightly to be more explicit, but it did answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

He means that function arguments may be implicitly converted, but something that would form `*this` for the function will never be implicitly converted.

Comment: can u pls eloborate. What is author means parameter list

Comment: @user: "parameter" is another word for "argument".  So the parameter list is just the list of arguments for the function.

Comment: No. "parameter" is not another word for "argument". *parameter* is what you mention when defining the function; *argument* is actual value which you pass to the function when calling it.

Comment: @Nawaz: in other words, to keep it simple, "parameter" is another word for "argument". It gets the point across, so why muddle the point further?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is what does author mean
>   in above statment "only if they are
>   listed in the parameter list" ? What
>   is parameter list?

What he meant is that the parameter list in your constructor(s):

```
class Rational
{
  public:
     Rational (int a);  // <-- here 'a'
     Rational (double b); //<-- here 'b'
};
```

If you've these two constructors in your class, then you can write

```
Rational result1 = oneHalf * 2; //2 is int, so it converts into Rational(2)
Rational result2 = oneHalf * 2.9; //2.9 is double, so it converts into Rational(2.9)
```